# Opening Eclipse ADT project folder in Android Studio ( when I have not exported folder)

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have a project folder which has source code developed using eclipse ADT. I got this folder from some friend.

I am using Android Studio and I am not able to figure out how to open that folder  in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you try exporting project with gradle from eclipse?

Comment: No. The Project is not exported from eclipse ADT.
I don't have eclipse ADT.

Comment: Do you have just .java classes or whole project ?

Comment: I have the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See more  details at [official guide](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

> To migrate existing Android projects, simply import them using Android Studio:
>
> 1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
> 2. Click Import Non-Android Studio project.
> 3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
> 4. In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)
>
> Android Studio properly updates the project structure and creates the
> appropriate Gradle build file.

**Update:**

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Non-Android Studio project.
3. Locate the project you from Eclipse, expand it, select folder. Click Ok
4. AS will open Wizard to import project from Eclipse.

Comment: Since it was not "exported" from Eclipse ADT, There is no build.gradle file in the project directory.
Is there anyway to do without that?